# I want to 'pase xml and serve objects in rest api

Tags: java

`   This is my xml code.Iam very new to restservice.

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <departments>
        <deptname name="Research">
            <employee>
                <eid>r-001</eid>
                <ename>Dinesh R</ename>
                <age>35</age>
                <deptcode>d1</deptcode>
               <deptname>Research</deptname>
                <salary>20000</salary>
              </employee>
            </deptname>
            <deptname name="Sales">
             <employee>
                <eid>s-001</eid>
                <ename>Kanmani S</ename>
                <age>35</age>
                <deptcode>d2</deptcode>
                <deptname>Sales</deptname>
                <salary>30000</salary>
              </employee>
             </deptname>
           </departments>
```

By using this xml i want to create Restservice.I have tried , i created java classes for that(i don't know that correct or not ).but i am stuck in controller in that area how i will mapping.

Comment: what platform are you using?

Comment: Show us the java code you have so far and explain what your issue is with it.

Comment: I am using java and i wrote the code in springboot

Comment: This is departments.java----@XmlRootElement(name="departments")

 public class Departments {

 List<Department> deptname;//getter and setter

Comment: ---Department.java----public class Department {
  @XmlAttribute(name = "deptname")
   private String name;

   @XmlElement(name = "employee")
   private List<Employee> employee = new ArrayList<>();//getter and setter---------------------------------Employee.java-----public class Employee {
 private String eid; 
 private String ename;  
 private String age; 
 private String deptcode; 
 private String deptname;
 private String salary; 
 List<Employee> employee;//getter and setter

Comment: The above classes are the java classes i created .Could you please update me sir whether it is correct or not .and then give me idea how to mapping in controller in rest service.

Comment: seems you want to 'pase xml and serve objects in rest api', if so you can edit your title to something like that. and, put all your code into question, not comments.

Comment: Hii sir, i tried to  put all code into question but it was not taken ,it showing error  like more characters.I am  new to  this one .Today only i started to ask the questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplest way, in my opinion
1) create a Departments pojo
2) create Department pojo which will be composed (composition) into departments
3) create a regular springboot controller, ensure the controller method produces and consumes application/xml 
4) include below dependency in your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

here is my example, 
Departments.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Departments {
   private List<Department> department;

   public List<Department> getDepartment() {
    return department;
   }

   public void setDepartment(List<Department> department) {
    this.department = department;
   }

}
```

Department.java

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class Department {
  private String name;
  private String id;
  private int employeeCount;
  public String getName() {
    return name;
  }
  public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
  public String getId() {
    return id;
  }
  public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
  public int getEmployeeCount() {
    return employeeCount;
  }
  public void setEmployeeCount(int employeeCount) {
    this.employeeCount = employeeCount;
  }
  @Override
  public String toString() {
    return "Department [name=" + name + ", id=" + id + ", employeeCount=" + 
           employeeCount + "]";
  }
  public Department() { }
  public Department(String name) { 
    this.name = name;
  }
  public Department(String name, String id) {
    this.name=name;
    this.id=id;
  }
  public Department(String name, String id, int employeeCount) {
    this.name=name;
    this.id=id;
    this.employeeCount = employeeCount;
  }
}
```

SpringBootApplication.java

```
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = {"test.controllers","test.main", "test.model"})
public class ServiceApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
  }
}
```

SpringController

```
@RestController
public class GreetingController {

    @RequestMapping("/hello/{name}")
    String hello(@PathVariable String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }

    @PostMapping(path = "/departments", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_VALUE)
    @ResponseBody
    Departments newEmployee(@RequestBody List<Department> departments) {
            Departments departmentsObj = new Departments();
            for(Department department : departments) {
                System.out.println(department);
            }
        departmentsObj.setDepartment(departments);

        return departmentsObj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply sir, i will try to do.